# How to make to see the output result to execute PL/SQL from SQL Plus?

Tags: oracle, plsql

When i run PL/SQL statment from SQL Plus,I don't see my output result.However,it was successful completed but it don't show output result.

My code is here

```
DECLARE 
message varchar2(20):= 'Hello World';
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line(message);
END;
/
```

> RESULT: PL/SQL is successfully completed.

It didn't show Hello World output.

Answer (score 3):

You need use the command `set serveroutput on` to configure buffering for `dbms_output` like below. Check this [Oracle Community Post](https://community.oracle.com/thread/656401?tstart=0)

```
set serveroutput on size 15000;
```

Comment: I got it.Thanks for your answer. :)

Comment: @JENNY, Consider accepting the answer if it helped by clicking the check button under voting button.